# Upon loading a track, the CDJ 2000 automatically goes through very quickly (~5 sec per one min of track)

Tags: repair, equipment, dj

Whenever I load a new track, it automatically goes through very quickly, unless I touch the jog, in which case everything goes back to normal:

Any idea what could occur this issue to appear and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the problem.  At what time does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you touch the jogwheel right as the track starts does it then play normally?

One of the first things I'd check is that the laser is sliding smoothly on the guide rod. I'm wondering if maybe it's getting hung up and then "popping" through the rough spot. I fixed similar behavior on a CDJ-100S by cleaning the guide rod with isopropyl then lubing it with powdered graphite

My other thought is that the board is receiving a jogwheel clockwise signal until you touch it. Is there a calibrate mode or can you unhook the jogwheel from the main PCB to see if the behavior stops?

Aside from that, if I couldn't find a service manual and had a second CDJ I'd start swapping parts until it was fixed then order that replacement part. If you've got experience working on electronics and can keep from losing buttons when you crack the case open they're pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

I think your CD player is broken. It needs qualified repair, assuming that's possible, or replacement.